# PHP cURL login fails

Tags: php, curl

There is a website http://www.tremorgames.com and I want to do a cURL login. I have a code which I use on my server http://shalva97.x10.mx/tremorlogin/ but it just does not work, but after a lot of testing I decided to install Apache on my PC and tested the exactly same code and it worked.

Here is the code :

```
<?php

$url="http://www.tremorgames.com/index.php"; 

$postdata = "loginuser=shalva&loginpassword=shalva&Submit=&saveme=1"; 

$ch = curl_init();
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url, 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postdata,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array("Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4", "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "Connection: keep-alive"),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => "cookies.txt", //Save cookies
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => "cookies.txt", //Cookies located
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://www.tremorgames.com/index.php',
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip,deflate'
));
echo curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Executing this same code on both my PC and server, I get different headers, on PC it receives multiple "Set-Cookie" header, but on server it is only one.

Why it does not work on the server? Why it works on my PC?

Comment: Please tell us that those aren't your real credentials. If so, you need to change them immediately.

Comment: oops... ok i changed pass everything is fine now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after a lot of thinking i found out that it is not only headers is sent but the ip and my location. The site does not allow logins from other countries thats why it didnot loged in, the code is correct and it was all about server location. i hope this will help others who also try to do same thing.